# MVC 4 Redirect when session ends

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, redirect, authentication

I have an mvc 4 application and I want to redirect to the login screen when the session times out.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't that happen automatically? The first time the user tries to access a protected page with an expired session, they'll have to re-authenticate to view it. What are you looking for?

Comment: @vaughn - When the server session times out or when authentication expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do the following to fix this

1. Change the web config for the session worked
2. I was overriding the cookie on the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest event and had to update the expiry date.
3. set the form authentication to

> httpOnlyCookies="true"

4. added javascript setInterval to pop up after 4 mins and call the logout script. abandon the session and log the user off

Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Add in web.config file

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>
```

I think it will help too.

Comment: Hi, I did that but that seems to remove the cookie and not the session. It keeps me still logged in.

Comment: Did you try with creating your custom ActionFilterAttribute ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with creating your ActionFilterAttribute ?? Action filters allow you to overide OnActionExecuting and it calls before an action method and this can be applied to any of your controller and then write code in there to check for the expiration of a session. Try this I think it can help.